# Access 2013: Form adding a totals row but only for certain records

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a form with a subform that uses a similar control source for each of the respective premiums (Decr Life, Level Life, AH, AcDD). In the subform, I am only expecting one record in the datasheet that sums each of the premiums but for some reason some of the records appear to have a "totals" whereas others do not. See screenshots 1 and 2 below. This may not be a totals row but it is a row, I do not want to show or at the very least I would like to understand why it shows. This extra row happens for some records with only one premium type too but I could not post another picture.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

`=DLookUp("[Sum Of AH Monthly Benefit]","[Sum_AH]","[Customer ID] = " & Forms("NewB-Premiums Form")("[Customer ID]"))`

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7GcK.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze0Pd.png)

Comment: That looks like a New Record row displaying default values. Somehow the DefaultValue property is set with values from the existing record.

Comment: @June7 There are no default values set in the properties.  Also, it only happens on certain records. The option to delete this row is disabled.

Comment: That is the New Record Row symbol at the left. So why those values are showing is a mystery. New Record Row cannot be deleted because it isn't an existing record so there is nothing to delete. Try setting the subform AllowAdditions property to No. Otherwise, I would have to examine form design. Sorry.

Comment: @June7, Setting the AllowAdditions Property to No on the subform solved it! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[June7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7607190/june7)
Try setting the subform AllowAdditions property to No.